# Added HTML formatting on Integer.ToString()

Tags: c#, html-table, outlook

Looking for pointers on a most peculiar problem.

I am creating an HTML table with 4 fields for an email to be displayed in Outlook.

The problematic output in the email is as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>APC</td>
  <td>M05</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>APC</td>
  <td>M06</td>
  <td>0&lt; /td&gt;</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>APC</td>
  <td>M07</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
</tr>
```

Note the added `&lt; /td&gt;` for M06.

The code that generates the output is:

```
public class StatusTableLine
{
    public string FeedType { get; set; }
    public string Period   { get; set; }
    public string Attempts { get; set; }
    public string Status   { get; set; }

    public StatusTableLine(string feedType, string period, string attempts, string status)
    {
        FeedType = feedType;
        Period = period;
        Attempts = attempts;
        Status = status;
    }

    public string AsHtml()
    {
        return string.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td>",
                    FeedType,
                    Period,
                    Attempts,
                    Status);
    }
}
```

Background information:

- FeedType is a hardcoded string value in the C# code.
- Period is a varchar value obtained from MSSQL database. This originates from user input.
- Attempts is from the following Linq statement: `var attempts = allAttempts.Count().ToString();`
- Status is from database, originating from hardcoded values in a C# input.

Since it only seems to happen on one row (M06) repeatedly, and only in one database (UAT, to which I don't have direct debug access), I am very much leaning toward the user input being duff.

But what kind of character(s) sequence in Period can change and add HTML characters to another field (which is filled by `.Count().ToString()`)? Some weird kind of escape char sequence?

I am aware it's a very specific question but if anyone has ideas it'd be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you add logging to see what the output of `AsHtml()` is? It may not be the same as what is rendered in the actual email.

Comment: I would change `public string Attempts { get; set; }` to `public int Attempts { get; set; }` as you don't need a string type here.

Comment: It looks like Attempts is being assigned something other than a number.. I'd validate Attempts before assigning it.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Fair comment, I'll add that. It will block duff entry from the other code, regardless of how direct that actually is.

Comment: @stuartd Are you thinking processing subsequent to the AsHtml() method in my code? Or are you hinting at non-code impact such as protocols or Outlook HTML processing?